# How to receive multiple data points from the user without making a new variable each time

Tags: c#

I'm starting to learn c#, and for one of my first projects I want to take multiple numbers from the user through Console.ReadLine, using a for loop. These numbers will be 0-9 and I'm trying to algorithmically guess the user's next numbers at a greater rate than random. I do not know how to take multiple data points in through after the first one, since I do not want to make a new variable for each new data point. How do I take in multiple input from the user, through a for loop, and store them for later analyzing.

Comment: Your looking for a `List<>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/arrays-and-collections

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("type in a number: ");
                numbers.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
```

Comment: An explanation of what the code does, specially for someone who's starting to learn, would be very useful.

Comment: @Alejandro you're right.

here is generic collection List<here you can pass any type> (that is what 'generic' word means), you create this list and initialize it before entering the for loop. then you ask user to type in a number for 9 times, and each time you capture what he typed by Console.ReadLine() method. But Console.ReadLine() has 'string' return type, and your list must contain only int values, so before adding those to list, you parse string values to integers. then you can use that list containing all the 9 values and do whatever you want. hope it was useful for you.